# Will a gas rotate as fast as the spherical container it is contained within?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, rotation

Let's say I have a sealed spherical glass container 30 cm in diameter which contains plain air.
The glass container is rotated about its axis at 1 revolution per minute.

My question is, would the gas also rotate at 1 revolution per minute within this sealed glass container?

Comment: What makes you think it would or wouldn't?

Comment: It depends on the viscosity of the gas...?

Comment: It depends very much on how long the cylinder has been rotating. Think of how one can test whether or not an egg has been boiled by giving the egg a spin.

Answer (score 0):

Given viscous effects, that is indeed the case if:

1. We are looking at a steady state system
2. It is not a rarefied gas (i.e. at pressures much lower than atmospheric)
3. The walls of the container are rough enough such that the gas molecules don't 'slip' over the surface but can be assumed at the same angular velocity (i.e. the no-slip condition)

Point 2 is important because when rarefied, gas molecules will simply bounce around without interacting with each other which is not a very effective method of momentum transfer.

In general, it is rarefied if the so-called Knudsen number:
$$\text{Kn}=\frac{\lambda}{L}$$
where $\lambda$ is the molecular length scale (mean free path of the molecules) and $L$ is the characteristic length scale of the system. If these are comparable (i.e. $\text{Kn}\sim1$), molecules rarely interact through collisions and we consider the gas rarefied. If the mean free path is much smaller than the system (i.e. $\text{Kn}\ll1$), then molecules often interact with each other through collisions in which they exchange momentum. In that case we can consider the continuum approximation to fluid dynamics; we can consider flow fields rather than individual molecular motion.